# Tests within columns R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame, which rows are protein ID and columns observations. I have 3 groups of 20 observations each. I would like to perform statistical analysis between groups. Which R code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information with example of dataset
Maybe u looking for something like that:

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(1:5,3),
               y=runif(15,2,50))
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(x)%>%
  summarise(mn=mean(y),
            sm=sum(y),
            md=median(y),
            sd=sd(y))
```